# Pass objects inside SOAP functions on SOAP Client

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap, soap-client

I need to call soap WSDL from PHP platform. SOAP request consists of SOAP object inside SOAP body function.

Sample working SOAP request is as below,

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ser:f1>
<a1>
<number xsi:type="xsd:string">720</number>
<newStatus xsi:type="xsd:string">2</newStatus>
</a1>
</ser:f1>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

f1 is a SOAP function and the is a another argument inside this as a1.

I need to call this from phpsoapclient or NuSOAP.

My below sample code (NUSOAP) is not working,

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("https://xxxx?wsdl");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$result = $client->call("f1", array("number" => "720","newStatus" => "2"),'','');
```

If anyone can, please provide me a SOAPCLIENT code from php or NuSOAP.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$client = new nusoap_client($url, true);
```

hope this help :)